# S3 InvalidDigest when calling the PutObject operation

Tags: python, amazon-s3, base64, boto3, md5

I am trying to create an object in an S3 bucket from a string, using Python and [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html). I want to send an MD5 with my upload request, so I can verify the upload's integrity.

The [docs for `S3.Client.put_object`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) say

> **ContentMD5** (*string*) -- The base64-encoded 128-bit MD5 digest of the message

I have tried the following code to set the `ContentMD5` argument:

```py
import boto3

def base64_encoded_md5_of_string(s: str) -> str:
    from hashlib import md5
    from base64 import b64encode

    hash_digest = md5(s.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    base64_bytes = b64encode(hash_digest.encode('utf-8'))
    base64_str = str(base64_bytes, 'utf-8')
    return base64_str

S3_BUCKET_NAME = '<redacted>'
S3 = boto3.client('s3')

csv_str = 'foo,bar,baz\nquz,vi,fam'
md5 = base64_encoded_md5_of_string(csv_str)

print(f'MD5: {md5}')

response = S3.put_object(
    Bucket=S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    Body=csv_str,
    ContentEncoding='utf-8',
    ContentType='text/csv',
    ContentMD5=md5,
    Key='<redacted>',
)
```

When I run the code, I get the output below:

```
MD5: NjNiMDE0OTI5MDcyY2M2OWFhMmM4N2ViM2FmMjM4Y2E=
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shane/src/test_s3_boto3_upload.py", line 20, in <module>
    response = S3.put_object(
  File "/home/shane/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 391, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/shane/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 719, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidDigest) when calling the PutObject operation: The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid.
```

What have I done wrong so that my `base64_encoded_md5_of_string` function returns an invalid MD5 digest?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60556534/4800344 and try the answer there - if that doesn't work, update your question :)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary That worked! If you convert your comment into an answer, I can accept it. Or my question could be closed as a duplicate of the one whose answer you linked to.

Comment: Wonderful! I will mark this to be closed as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/60556534/4800344 to redirect anyone else with the same question to one source of truth (and answer) :)